# Need to use pyperclip on heroku

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, heroku, pyperclip

I need to use pyperclip on heroku on a selenium app to copy something to clipboard but as the platform runs a 'headless' browser and has no GUI, a clipboard is obscure. is it possible for me to make this work somehow?

Comment: I don't know about pyperclip, but for me, copying stuff from a headless browser does not present any real issues when using selenium

Comment: do you really need clipboard? Can't you save in file and later read from file? maybe better describe why you need clipboard - maybe someone find method to do this without clipboard.

Comment: @C.Peck how do you do it sir? i only know to copy with pyperclip

Comment: @furas yeah its because i need to send_keys() a large body of text and sending it as a string takes too long. also i tried executescript but my the text box is weird. its the code text box on diffchecker.com and i don't know how to access its value attribute. seems like it is sectioned out line by line
edit: send_keys (string) takes too long so i want to use send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'v')

Comment: you should write it in question at start - it better explain problem.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium can press ctrl + c to copy.

To copy using python and Selenium, you can use the following code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

actions = ActionChains(driver)

actions.key_down(Keys.CONTROL)

actions.send_keys("c")

actions.key_up(Keys.CONTROL)

actions.perform()
```

Comment: i think this will work if i upload my files somewhere to scrape from. i need to copy a string already present in my code to clipboard and then paste into diffchecker.com. thank u